# Does Google Analytics count URL Forwarding as referral traffic?

Tags: redirect, google-analytics

We have two domains that we'll call `a-example.com` and `b-example.com`.

`b-example.com` has URL Forwarding set up (in GoDaddy) to redirect to `a-example.com/somepage`.

Will Google Analytics log `b-example.com` as a **referral** on `a-example.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include utm URL parameters on the redirect.

`b-example.com`redirects to `a-example.com/somepage?utm_source=b-example.com&utm_medium=vanity&utm_campaign=vanityb`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what we did.

Answer (score 0):

I visited `b-example.com` and was redirected to `a-example.com`.  In `a-example.com`, the value of `document.referrer` is `""`.

Therefore, Google Analytics would not be able to credit `b-example.com` with the referral.